# Passing value to callback function

Tags: java, android, checkbox, sdk, reference

I want my code to do something dynamically on check / uncheck event of a checkbox.
I have this code:

```
checkConfidentiality.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked==true)
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Argh").setMessage("YEEEEEEEE").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();  

                        else
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Argh").setMessage("NOOOOOOOO").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();  

            }
        });
```

In this particular case, I get an error in the AllertDialog Declaration, of course because  in the callback function the "this" variable doesn't  make any sense.
The question is, How can i pass a variable ("this" of the parent scope, or any other variable) to the callback function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
YourClassName.this
```

should do the trick.

Or you should write yout custom class. For instance

```
private class MyOnCheckedChangeListener implement CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
      private Context context;
      public MyOnCheckedChangeListener (Context context) {
         this.context = context;
      }

       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
       }

}
```

and use it like:

```
checkConfidentiality.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyOnCheckedChangeListener(this));
```

check for typo

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass the activity, you need to pass the context. You can use
`buttonView.getContext()` instead of `this`:

```
checkConfidentiality.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked==true)
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(buttonView.getContext()).setTitle("Argh").setMessage("YEEEEEEEE").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();  

                        else
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(buttonView.getContext()).setTitle("Argh").setMessage("NOOOOOOOO").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();  

            }
        });
```